# Why would SQL Server Profiler not show some TextData values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I am running a trace against a SQL Server database that I have that makes extensive use of stored procedures. I have noticed that in some cases, when executing a stored procedure, the RPC:Starting and SP:Starting events have no data in the TextData or BinaryData fields, but when executing a different stored procedure, the same events show the SQL statement that is being executed. Of course, the issue I am trying to investigate is related to the stored procedure whose TextData is not being displayed.

What would prevent SQL Server Profiler (and XEvent Profiler, I checked there as well) from populating the TextData/BinaryData fields of the RPC:Starting and SP:Starting events? I can see the stored procedure is being called, as its name appears in the ObjectName field, and I can see the individual statements within the stored procedure being executed via the SP:StmtStarting event (which **does** populate the TextData field), but I really want to see what parameters are being passed to it.